# question about buttons and passing a value

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

i have in my aspx page

```
<%
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        LinkButton1.CommandArgument=i.ToString();
%>    
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnCommand="LinkButton1_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
<% 
    }
%>
```

how can i pass a value in my aspx.cs page like:

```
protected void LinkButtonStergeArticol_Click(object sender,CommandEventArgs e)
{
    String id = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
}
```

?

i know it's not correct because i have more LinkButtons with the same ID, but is there any solution for my problem in this scenario? Or can you suggest me another approach?

i need to have a linkbutton for every item i have in an array. then i need to pass the item's index so that i can delete it in my aspx.cs page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you use a [Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx) or [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.aspx) to generate that list of controls? Those are designed to generate a list of controls.

Comment: if i don't won't find a solution for LinkButtons then i will try ListView.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like following?

```
<%
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        //LinkButton1.CommandArgument=i.ToString();
%>    
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" 
                        runat="server" 
                        OnCommand="LinkButton1_Click" 
                        CommandName="SomeCommand"
                        CommandArgument="<%= i%>"></asp:LinkButton>
<% 
    }
%>
```

Comment: I was thinking something similar. But also use the `<%= i%>` in the ID attribute (and not in the OnCommand).

Comment: i tried CommandArgument="<%= i%>"> but what i'm getting is the String "<%= i%>". i tried also with '' and it the same result. and without "" or '' i get an error.